# How to create Google sheets range off of 2 separate columns

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange

I need to create a range off of two separate columns within a sheet.

Let's say column A is my index, while column D is third party index.

When using VLOOKUP i can lookup my index to find 3rd party index by using $A:$D range:

`VLOOKUP('index-to-lookup'; 'my sheet'!$A:$D; 4; false)`

However, I need to be able to lookup the other way around as well: knowing 3rd party index I want to find my index.

I've tried already:
`VLOOKUP('index-to-lookup'; 'my sheet'!$A:$D; -1; false)`
`VLOOKUP('index-to-lookup'; 'my sheet'!$D:$A; 4; false)`
`VLOOKUP('index-to-lookup'; 'my sheet'!$D:$A; -1; false)`

as well as using arrays:
`VLOOKUP('index-to-lookup'; {'my sheet'!$A:$A, 'my sheet'!$D:$D}; -1; false)`

combining single columns with importrange etc.
but neither have worked so far.

There's no answer for similar problem to be founud.

Comment: Welcome! [**vlookup vs index match**](https://www.google.com/search?q=vlookup+vs+index+match) -  `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH('index-to-lookup',D:D,0))` or `=VLOOKUP('index-to-lookup',{D:D,A:A},2,0)`

Comment: Unfortunately, the second option to combine 2 columns into an array, results in an error. I'll try INDEX MATCH though. Thank you!

Comment: Error? What about `=VLOOKUP('index-to-lookup',ARRAYFORMULA({D:D,A:A}),2,0)`?

Comment: This also results in an error, seems like it's impossible to combine existing columns with just a comma "," into an array. There's probably a function for that, that appends each row, but none that I could find.

Comment: Fortunately though, your idea to use INDEX and MATCH works perfectly and solves my problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JohnSUN your suggestion to use INDEX and MATCH alternatively to VLOOKUP begs the question: which one is quicker and more lightweight to use, less resource-demanding etc.? Do you know of any places where these could have been compared?

Comment: The words **vlookup vs index match**  in my first comment is a link that should open a long, very long list of articles comparing the two ways of finding information in spreadsheets.

Comment: @JohnSUN thank you for sharing your experience. After a while of research I have been able to find a first answer. I'll continue to research the topic and give it a trial-and-error performance comparisons on the fly. Hopefully I'll be back in a few years to share my experience with others.

Answer (score 0):

With keys to look up in `A2:A`, you can find them in `'my sheet'!D2:D`, returning the values in `'my sheet'!A2:A`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup( 
  A2:A; 
  { 'my sheet'!D2:D \ 'my sheet'!A2:A }; 
  2; 
  false 
) ) )
```

Comment: Wait, is it backslash that appends whole columns in GS arrays? Is therefore an arrayformula necessary?

Comment: The `arrayformula()` wrapper lets `vlookup()` process all the search keys in the column `A2:A` in one go. You can leave it out if you want to process those search keys one by one. In the event your spreadsheet locale uses commas `,` as decimal separators, you will have to use semicolons `;` as formula argument separators and backslashes `'\'` as [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) horizontal separators.

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)